# Was Monica the one who convinced Richard?

Tags: silicon-valley

In the first episode of *Silicon Valley*, Monica offers a ride back home to a confused Richard. And as soon as he comes home, he reveals that he wants to take the money and build a company rather than selling it away.

**So, was Monica the one who convinced Richard?**

Comment: On the show, Richard doesn't just listen to other people's advice in cases like this. He has to arrive at the decision himself. Although it's been a long time since I watched the first episode, I recall that Richard was thinking about both possibilities, and weighing the has pros and cons of each. I think that during the car ride he talked through both options, and Monica actively listened, but in the end Richard made up his own mind rather than being "convinced".

Comment: I saw Monica and Richard, jumped here to see what Monica Geller did ti Richard Burke. sorry, wrong show :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to me, Monica did play a role in influencing Richard to take the decision. In the episode, after speaking to Gregory and Belson, Richard becomes sick and starts throwing up due to indecisiveness, panic and stress. He then sees Monica in the parking lot. They start talking and she tells him just how big the compression engine idea could become and asks him to take the money.

"This is your baby.This is game changing. Don’t you want to be in the driver seat when that happens?" she demands.

This conversation with Monica would have definitely help shape Richard's decision.